# Why am I not getting 10 for the square root of 100 from the FPU in NASM?

Tags: ubuntu, floating-point, nasm, 32-bit, fpu

I'm trying to learn a bit about floating point operations in NASM Assembly for 32-bit programs in Ubuntu.

I'm interested in getting a number's square root. This is what I tried:

```
SECTION .data
num: dd 100
var: dd 0

SECTION .text
global main
main:

fld dword [num]
fsqrt
fstp dword [var]
mov EAX,[var]
```

I was expecting `EAX` to be 10. But GDB says that it is `0x1be24630` (`467813936`), which by the way I'm not sure how to convert to something more readable - but I think that if the result was 10, it would actually show up as 10, no?

What am I doing wrong here? Or is `0x1be24630` actually 10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is [`FILD`](http://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/archive/fall2001/books/labmanual/inst-ref-fild.html) and `FISTP`:

```
fild dword [num]   ; load a dword integer and convert it to floating point
fsqrt
fistp dword [var]  ; convert to dword integer and store in var
```

Alternatively you could do it like this:

```
num: dd 100.0  ; note the .0, which makes this a floating point value

fld dword [num]    ; load single-precision floating point value
fsqrt
fistp dword [var]  ; convert to dword integer and store in var
```